# About google app engine entity delete

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i want to delete all of the entity.
i found that if i want to delete a entity,

```
// Key employeeKey = ...;
datastore.delete(employeeKey);
```

Upper code can delete a one entity. but i want to delete all of the entities.
is there any good way to delete at once? only can delete every entity each?

Answer (score 0):

The delete method can take an argument of `Iterable<Key>`, so do something like

```
List<Key> keys = Arrays.asList(key1, key2, key3);
datastore.delete(keys);
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#delete%28java.lang.Iterable%29

Comment: Yes, you should get keys and pass them to the delete method.